# Abbreviations for variants of mLL?

Tags: logic, notation, soft-question, terminology, linear-logic

**1. Context**
There are various variants of multiplicative linear logic (*mLL*). I am wondering how those various relatives of *mLL* are conventionally abbreviated.

**2. Question**
What are common abbreviations for the following relatives of *mLL*:

- *mLL* without units?
- *mLL* without units and without cut?
- *mLL* without negation and without exchange (but with units)?

Comment: See [here](https://www.pls-lab.org/en/MLL)

Comment: and [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/)

Comment: The cases I am asking about are not covered at the linked websites, I am afraid.